# Usando filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,"var_name") vs. $_POST

Tags: php, post, input

Eu tenho a seguinte variável input no meu formulário:

```
<input class="caption_text" type="text" name="caption[]" required/>
```

Que eu criar dinamicamente com JS.

Depois de submeter eu testo o seguinte:

```
$mycaption = \filter_input_array(\INPUT_POST, 'caption');
foreach ($mycaption as $eachInput) {
    echo "Caption " . $eachInput . "<br>";
}
```

Eu descobri que o código acima não funcionou.

Contudo, unsando $_POST, assim:

```
$cpost = $_POST["caption"];

foreach ($cpost as $eachInput) {
    echo "Caption " . $count. " - " . $eachInput . "<br>";
}
```

Em seguida, ele funciona como esperado.

Alguém pode, por favor, me dizer por que a primeira abordagem não funciona?

Comment: O que são aquelas barras invertidas no seu código?

Comment: Está usando o `filter_input_array` e mandando ele validar o que ? Lógico que o retorno será `null`, tente adicionar alguma expressão para validar o que esperar receber neste campo.

Comment: Olá, não quero validar nada, apenas buscar a varíavel submetida. Recomenda-se não usar mais a variável global $_POST direto e sim através de um filter_input.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste simulando o código que postou e formulei o código abaixo com o uso da função:

```
<?php
$filtro = array( 
    'caption' => array(
        # aqui pode variar de acordo com o valor esperado do seu input
        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING,
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
    )
);
$form = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filtro); 
if (array_key_exists("caption", $form))
{
    foreach($form['caption'] ...)
    {
         # ...
    }
}
```

**Saída**

```
<?php
var_dump($form);
# array(1) { ["caption"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) } }
```

Comment: Olá Wilian, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Visto que o NetBeans IDE avisa: "do not access superglobal $_POST array directly", eu estou utilizando os "filter_input" conforme recomendado. Para todas as varíaveis do meu form eu faço isso e funciona certinho. No entanto, para esse campo que é um array (caption[ ]) ele não funciona. Essa caption é um array que crio dinamicamente e recebe um texto normal, apenas para descrever as imagens selecionadas. Por ora, vou continuar acessando assim: $caption = $_POST['caption'];